# Metamask RPC methods do not exist

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, metamask

I have been following a tutorial on how to create my first Web3js application with solidity and react.
The tutorial was going great until I fall into this problem with metamask RPC.
The tutorial I have been following is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wn_Kb3MR_cU&t=6333s&ab_channel=JavaScriptMastery

Right now I'm getting the following errors when trying to run function from `ethereum`:

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: The method "accounts " does not exist / is not available.

inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: The method "eth_accounts " does not exist / is not available. 

uncaught (in promise) {code: -32601, message: 'The method "eth_accounts " does not exist / is not available.', data: {…}, stack: '{\n  "code": -32601,\n  "message": "The method \\"eth…beogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-0.js:18:167275)'}

uncaught (in promise) {code: -32601, message: 'The method "eth_requestAccounts " does not exist / is not available.', data: {…}, stack: '{\n  "code": -32601,\n  "message": "The method \\"eth…beogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-0.js:18:167275)'}
```

The file that runs this is a context file `TransactionContext.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { contractABI, contractAddress } from '../utils/constants';

export const TransactionContext = React.createContext({} as any);

const { ethereum } = window as any;

const getEthereumContract = () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const transactionsContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

    console.log({
        provider,
        signer,
        transactionsContract
    })
}

export const TransactionProvider = ({ children }: any) => {

    const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState('');

    const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async () => {
        if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask!");

        const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts '});

        console.log(accounts);
    }

    const connectWallet = async () => {
        try {
            if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask!");
            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts '});
            setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            throw new Error('No Ethereum object.')
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkIfWalletIsConnected();
    }, [])

    return (
        <TransactionContext.Provider value={{ connectWallet }}>
            {children}
        </TransactionContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 issues in your contract:

1- you are not returning the contract from `getEthereumContract`. it should be

```
const getEthereumContract = () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const transactionsContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

    return transactionsContract
}
```

I dont see you are using here yet but you might get bug in the future:

2- Error says `'The method "eth_accounts " does not exist ..`. you have extra space here "eth_accounts ". should be

```
 const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts'});
```

3- this is similar to second. You have extra space

```
 const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
```

Comment: Yep, that's it, what a silly mistake of mine

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify for which account you want to get the signer provider.getSigner(account)

On click of your connect button add this

```
async function connectWalletHandler() {
  if (!ethereum) {
    console.log("Make sure you have Metamask installed");

    return;
  } else {
    console.log("Wallet exist");
  }

  const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

  if (accounts.length !== 0) {
  } else {
    console.log("No authorized account found");
  }
```

And put this code in you app.js

```
const [user,setUser]=useState(null);
Useeffect(()=>{
if (window.ethereum) {
    const isMetaMaskConnected = async () => {
      let provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const accounts = await provider.listAccounts();
      let account = null;
      if (accounts.length > 0) {
        account = accounts[0];
      }
      let signer = provider.getSigner(account);
      setUser({ provider: provider, signer: signer, account: account });
    };
    isMetaMaskConnected();
    window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", (chainId) => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", () => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  } else {
    
    }},[])
```

From now you have 3 option first user is null metamask not installed
2 user.account="" or null metamask installed and connected but locket
3 user.account have value this is when the wallet connected to the website and every thing

Comment: Could you please format your answer, show where these should be inserted, and separete the data into functions, it will be better so I can insert and test in my code and for good practises.

Comment: I have tested inserting this into the same file as the example above. I didn't get the error for `eth_accounts` but I got an error for `inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: The method "eth_requestAccounts " does not exist / is not available.`

Comment: See the answer now